# Android-version related issue in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, custom-font, eclipse-luna

In previously i have used Eclipse `juno` for android development at that time my app and those custom font everything was worked fine.After i have updated my Eclipse version to `Luna` for development.If i run the app in `Luna` environment my custom font is not working.Again i have rollback the `juno` version and run the app over here,it is working fine.My SDK also fully udated,this issue related to SDK or Eclipse

Why that the same app not worked in `Luna` Environment?Is there anything behind that the `Luna`...

Comment: Down voters please tell,whai i ask wrong from here?

Comment: I didn't downvote but you may want to explain your problem a bit further than just "not working" (errors > logcat, nothing happens > expected behaviour, ...). Have you considered using Android Studio ?